# How to hold focus on JFrame just like JOptionPane

Tags: java, swing, window, focus, joptionpane

I want to be focus on my own input frame just like JOptionPane (when click other space, my frame is flicker and grab focus like that).I tested that in requestfocus() but it doesn't work. Is there something worng on my code? Please help....

> Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().addAWTEventListener(new tool(), AWTEvent.FOCUS_EVENT_MASK);

```
class tool implements AWTEventListener{
@Override
    public void eventDispatched(AWTEvent arg0) {
        if(arg0.paramString().contains("FOCUS_LOST")){
            frame.toFront();
            frame.requestFocus();
            frame.requestFocusInWindow();
            window.toFront();
            window.requestFocus();
            window.requestFocusInWindow();
        }

        System.out.println(arg0.paramString()+" ppppp.......");

    }
}
```

Comment: *"I want to be focus on my own input frame just like JOptionPane"*  A better approach would be to ***not** break the user expectations of focus and modality.*

Comment: and (if frame == JFrame) frame.toFront();, frame.requestFocus();, frame.requestFocusInWindow(); doesn't works from the WinNT times